# Signalr hubs 404 not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, signalr

I'm trying to integrate Signalr into my web form project.

First, added the references using nugget

- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client;
- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core;
- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.System.Web;
- Microsoft.Owin;
- Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb;
- Microsoft.Owin.Security;
- Owin

My startup class:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(ns.App_Code.Startup))]
namespace ns 
{
 public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

My hub:

```
public class PositionHub : Hub
{
    static ConcurrentDictionary<int, List<string>> connectedUsers = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, List<string>>();


    public override Task OnConnected()
    {


        return base.OnConnected();
    }

}
```

Finally, the client-side:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.3.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/signalr/hubs") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {

            var logger = $.connection.positionHub;
            logger.start();

     });

    </script>
```

Also, added to web.config the following:

```
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true" />
```

and

```
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

When I run the app it gives the 404 error:
 GET http://localhost:41363/signalr/hubs 404 (Not Found)

This is not my first time using signalr, but it is the first time I have this issue, and been struggling for hours to solve it, with no luck...

Comment: check javascript in browser, are you getting all of them properly? if not try to add proper path for them like `~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.3.0.min.js`

Comment: Yes I am, its just signalr/hubs that doesnt get created, although the Startup class Configuration method gets called.

Comment: ok, then update that first reference.

Comment: @Bharat after updating, I got this,1) GET localhost:41363/signalr/hubs 400 (Bad Request) 2) Refused to execute script from 'localhost:41363/signalr/hubs'; because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Comment: go through this once https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#transport

Comment: Got this, signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%5D&_=1534496079997:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) . How I setting up the client:  `code`    <script type="text/javascript"> $(function () {
            debugger
            var connection = $.hubConnection("/signalr", { useDefaultPath: false });
            var contosoChatHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('myHub1');
            connection.start().done(function() {
                alert("started");
            });      });

    </script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice you don't have the following NuGet packages installed which are required when integrating SignalR with Javascript.

- [Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR)
  This package pulls in the server components and **JavaScript client** required to use SignalR in an ASP.NET application.
- [Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS/)
  **Script client** for ASP.NET SignalR.
  (*This one is included automatically by Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR above.)*

**EDIT**

Via the comments below we found out that OP's `web.config`file contained some url rewrite rules which intercepted the `/signalr/hubs` url.

Adding a rule to prevent this url from being rewritten solved the problem.

```
<rule name="signalR" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true"> 
    <match url="^signalr.*" /> <action type="None" /> 
</rule>
```

Comment: Strange, I added them with Nuget, but they dont appear on my project references list.

Comment: They were all included in the project.

Comment: OK; idd, they don't appear as reference. Can u please share the full web.config?

Comment: Here it is: paste.ofcode.org/S8eQCihMBDwhrNNxKU8Dbb

Comment: Can you try to disable the rewrite rules.

Comment: I'm confused with the last comment above on the question. I have your code running here ... Replace the clientside script with: $(function() { $.connection.hub.start(); var logger = $.connection.positionHub; });

Comment: GET http://localhost:41363/signalr/hubs 400 (Bad Request) this is what I get. It occurs on <script src="signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script> . Somehow the hub is not being created. Can you show me your web.config please?

Comment: The out-of-the-box one paste.ofcode.org/NgGtYEvUiWGWbFfy3x9ugn

Comment: The rewrite rule was conflicting it. I needed to add a new one         <rule name="signalR" enabled="true"  stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^signalr.*" />
          <action type="None" />
        </rule>

Comment: You were. Trying to give you the bounty ;)

Answer (score 0):

fix startup class namespace

```
namespace ns
```

to be

```
namespace TeltonikaSiteWebApplication.App_Code
```

Comment: put a debugger in Configuration method and make sure it is being calling

Answer (score 0):

The rewrite rule was conflicting it on web config was conflicting with signalr. I needed to add a new one to make it work.     . Thanks to @pfx on the guidance.